# Access nodejs application from URL on VPS

Tags: node.js

I have a VPS running apache on CentOS 6.5. I'm currently writing a node application to run on port 1234.

My question is that, how to access the node application via URL. Like `http://IP_ADDRESS:1234` or `http://MYDOMAIN:1234`?

Comment: If you have your domains DNS records correctly setup then either will be ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not actually a node issue. It was a firewall that was blocking all requests to the port 1234.

I found that [advanced policy firewall](https://www.rfxn.com/projects/advanced-policy-firewall/) (APF) was installed on my machine. All I had to do to allow connections to the required port is to edit APF config file located in `/etc/apf/conf.apf`.

Then add the required ports to the variable `IG_TCP_CPORTS=`

Finally, restart APF to apply effects

```
$ /usr/local/sbin/apf -r
```